# RegexValidator to not allow trailing white spaces in CharField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i want a regex validator on model char field which ll throw error if char field contains leading and trailing white spaces.

example : 
"__regex validator" : not valid

"regex validator__" : not valid

"regex validator" : valid

Thks in advance :)

- __ means white spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention a "model char field" this is what I'd suggest:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

field = models.CharField(max_length=100,
    validators=[RegexValidator(r"^\S.*\S$|^\S$|^$",
                               "This field cannot start or end with spaces.")])
```

The regexp above will disallow leading or trailing spaces but will allow an empty string. This will report an error if there is an issue. When you validate data entry, you generally want to *report* errors rather than *throw* (i.e. `raise`) them.

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried multiple regexes in an interactive Python session and got my wires crossed while testing. I've edited my answer.